# How to change label names at runtime in Struts

Tags: validation, jsp, struts, struts-1

My application uses Struts messages resources to show message on JSP file.

```
<message-resources parameter="ApplicationResources" />
```

This is what I have specified in my Struts XML file.

In my web application I want to give user the freedom to change the label name to some other name. How can I change the label name in Struts at run time, so that updated label is displayed on the screen.

I have tried updating the label using following code in `Action` class, but it updates the alert message shown on the screen and not the label.

```
ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();
messages.add("App.Screen.ScreenHeading", new ActionMessage("App.Screen.ScreenHeading", "My Heading"));
saveMessages(request, messages);
```

Comment: What a label are you talking? There're only `ul`/`li` options.

Comment: we have labels in jsp  <td width="120"  class="labelTextSelect"><span class="mandatory">*</span><bean:message key="App.Screen.ScreenHeading" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td> This labels are defined in property file. Let say in property file the value for this label is "Screen Heading", so in jsp it will be shown as "Screen Heading", but user want to rename the label to user defined value i.e. let say "My Screen Heading". How can it be acheived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions messages are used with the validation. Better you don't try to set request attributes using this approach because action message are incompatible to the newer versions of Struts framework and you might have problems upgrading those messages. Another approach is to use a form bean or request scope variable to provide the text used to substitute for the message displayed by `bean:message` tag.

```
request.setAttribute("App_Screen_ScreenHeading", "My Heading");
```

the JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<td width="120" class="labelTextSelect"><span class="mandatory">*</span>
<c:if test="${empty App_Screen_ScreenHeading}">
  <bean:message key="App.Screen.ScreenHeading" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty App_Screen_ScreenHeading}">
  <c:out value=${App_Screen_ScreenHeading}"/>
</c:if>
&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
```

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this. I have nearly 60 jsp's in my application, and writing this logic at each and every label and heading will be very much time consuming. Also when i add any new jsp into my application all the developers have to take care to write this logic in their jsp file.

Comment: 60 JSPs not a big stuff, if you don't use custom tags or Ajax to render a content, any template engine then you can still use JSP include tag or directive. JSTL has also an import tag with the same purpose. And I will strongly recommend to upgrade the Struts to the newest version.